# How can we attach all the activities on a lead to an account when the lead is converted?

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I am trying to convert a lead using

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE    IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

What happens to the activities of that lead? Do they also get attached to the converted account? If no how can we get them also moved for the contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation at https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/leads_notes.htm

```
All open and closed activities from the lead are attached to the account, contact, and opportunity
```